# JavaScript 2 strings not getting compared properly?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to compare 2 string to make sure they match. This is the code that im using:

```
var pass1 = document.getElementById("password1");
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("password2");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    if(pass1 != pass2){
        result.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
    }
    if(pass1 == pass2){
        //document.forms['register'].submit();  
    }
```

This was working last night but is not any more even when I use `===`, either way it says the string are a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing the elements, not the elements' current values.

Instead you should say: `if (pass1.value != pass2.value)`

Comment: Thank you :) our js teacher wasnt every good... ill accept your answer when i can. EDIT: can someone explain why the question got down voted?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
if (pass1.value != pass2.value){
```

ie, compare the elements value. Presently you are comparing the elements.